# Fstab Configuration Help

Tags: mount, fstab

Okay so I was messing around in the fstab file under /etc/ and I made a new partition which I could play around with, this partitions name is **/dev/sda2**.

So when I was messing around I did this configuration on my **/dev/sda2** partition. Once I was done, I rebooted the system and it didn't load the system and it only allowed me to configure the system via a Command Line interface terminal with no GUI or anything.

```
<file system> <mount point>    <type>  <options>   <dump>   <pass>
#/data on /dev/sda2
UUID=910d5659-9fe1-43d5-bff6-738459fcdbd /home/r00t/Document/mount-point ext4 relatime,ro,owner,errors=remount-rw 0 2
```

When mounting **/dev/sda2** I was playing around with the options column, by adding different options such as **relatime,ro,errors=remount-rw** so I think that may be a cause of the problem.

Comment: Tip for the next time you edit `/etc/fstab/`: Run `mount -a` afterwards before rebooting to make sure what you did was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is **errors=remount-rw**, acceptable valuse are : 
 **errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}**
This is what ext4 man page says EXT4(5) :

> The ext4 filesystem is an advanced level of the ext3 filesystem which incorporates scalability  and  reliability  enhancements  for
>          supporting large filesystem.
>   The options [list of options ...], errors, data_err ... are backwardly compatible with ext3 or ext2.

Also EXT2(5) says :

> errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}
>                 Define the behavior when an error is encountered.  (Either ignore errors and just mark the  filesystem  erroneous  and  continue, or remount the filesystem read-only, or panic and halt the system.)

Comment: a few hours after posting my question i did some troubleshooting and i eventually found that **errors=remount-rw** is not even an option but **errors=remount-ro** is but thanks for verifying this fam.

Comment: Also where did you get **errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}** from, was it from a man page or something?

Comment: @Qasim yes, check **man ext4**

Answer (score 0):

The root filesystem should not be mounted ro by default (unless your distro can work completely from RAM), but errors=remount-ro can be helpful. You did the other way around.

If you have trouble remounting the filesystem and editing fstab by hand, you could use a live system. the option `defaults` is a good start for a ext4 filesystem.

Comment: im not mouting 'the root' filesystem im mounting a ext4 filesystem from the /dev/sda partiton which will be mounted onto the root file system

Comment: Oh, I didn't read your fstab closely enough. Because your reboot failed, I assumed the root fs was involved. Did you check dmesg for error messages?